# Laravel Eloquent SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column ... in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am getting this error "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'disabled_at' in where clause is ambiguous"
although in my where I added the table name to precede the column, and also in the join statement, but it still gives me the above error.
Here is that code snipet:

```
        $name = ($params['query']) ? $params['query'] : '';
        $perPage = (isset($params['perpage']) && $params['perpage'] !== null) ? 
            intval($params['perpage']) : 50;

        $query = $this->with('sections');
              
        // search disabled users
        if ($disabled) {
            $query->withTrashed();
            // if not all, limit to disabled only
            if (!$allUsers) {
                $query->whereNotNull('users.disabled_at');
            }
        }

        // exclude name search when blank to increase query speed
        if ($name !== '') { 
            $query->join('sections', 'users.section_id', '=', 'sections.id');
            $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(users.title,' ',users.first_name,' ',users.last_name,' ',users.email,' ',sections.name)"), 'like', '%' . $name . '%');
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show the query by using DB::enableQueryLog() before query and get result by using dd(DB::getQueryLog());

Comment: You will get an idea of where the "disabled_at" column in the query is used.

Comment: Can you do a `dd($query->toSQL())` and share the result here? (or inspect it to see if there's any obvious issue you can fix yourself)

Comment: The error message suggests that there are multiple columns that have the same column name disabled_at. (table1.disabled_at and table2.disabled_at). Now your database doesnt know which disabled_at you are referring to. Are you sure the error happens here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, thank all you for your suggestions.
I figured out what the issue was by seeing the raw mysql query using your suggestions, outputting with `DB::enableQueryLog()` and `query->toSQL()`, the later actually is what worked for me. Basically the column `disabled_at` works as the soft delete `'deleted_at'`, so it's either NULL or has a timestamp, therefore what was happening was that the raw query had a "...where '.disabled_at' IS NULL..." by default (unbeknown to me), and because the sections table also has a 'disabled_at' column, it did not know to which of those 2 tables `disabled_at` belonged, so I had to specify the table with the following query"`whereNULL('users.disabled_at')`..." and not just let the default run.